# node js - How to save received file from telegram bot

Tags: node.js, stream, telegram, telegram-bot

How I can save a file from a stream or from an url in nodejs?
I have a telegram bot that will get files from users. I'm able to get the file url or the stream but I'm not sure how to save it in a temporary directory before process.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/) to the library I'm using

How I can proceed?Here is the code

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const process = require('process');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');


const token = process.env.TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN || '5xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
// Create a bot that uses 'polling' to fetch new updates
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});  

bot.onText(/\/echo(.+)/, async (msg, match) => {
  // 'msg' is the received Message from Telegram
  // 'match' is the result of executing the regexp above on the text content
  // of the message
  //const chatId = msg.chat.id;
});

bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
...
});


bot.on('document', async (data) => {
  console.log(data);

  // here I'm getting the file url  
  const fileURL = await bot.getFileLink(data.document.file_id);
  // the library have a method that give the ability to get the file stream. How I save it to a file?
  const stream = await bot.getFileStream(data.document.file_id);
  console.log(fileURL, stream);
});

//
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
const { createWriteStream } = require('fs');

stream.pipe(createWriteStream('your_file'));
```